Looking for name of Schwinn Le Tour variant above "Super" (mid 1980s)
I am looking for the name of Schwinn Le Tour variant above "Super" (mid 1980s).
I remember perusing Consumer Reports (and ended up getting a Super Le Tour) c. 1985.  At that time, there were like three variants of the Le Tour (low, medium, high performance).  I remember Super being the medium.  Can't remember the name of the highest end Le Tour.  Something like Master or Grand or Triumph.
Note:  I did try a lot of Googling, before crowdsourcing to here.

Was it maybe the Paramount? My brain is a lil foggy

Paramount does sound familiar but it may have been a product line after the mid-1980s. The question is specific to the LeTour line.

Here's an old catalog from 1980. The most expensive model listed seems to be" Voyageur".
You can also see some other catalogs here.
This page Show Le Tour Luxe.

I suspect the Voyageur is what I'm remembering (if that is a road bike).  Not the Le Tour Luxe.

Also price makes sense with my recollection.

Possibly the LeTour Luxe
In 1985 the lineup starting with the LeTour went like this:
LeTour
Super LeTour (sport)
LeTour Luxe (touring)
Voyageur
Voyageur SP
Tempo
Super Sport
Peloton
Here is the spec sheet for the LeTour Luxe

Source link

Thanks for the work.  I think it's the other answer and wasn't a Le Tour variant.  I know it wasn't a touring bike.
